# Creating new sockets dynamically based on URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am new to web-sockets in Java. I was able to create a web-socket, but I want to be able to open multiple different sockets based on the channel (room). Please note that I do not use STOMP.

I have tried adding a dynamic url as such: "/{someRoom}/chat", but when testing with multiple clients directing to different URLs they were all connecting to the same socket. Essentially my question is: is it possible to open new sockets dynamically? is this the right methodology or should I have them all use the same socket and route their messages based on the URL provided?

```
@EnableWebSocket
@Controller
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(alertsHandler(), "/{someRoom}/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*")
    .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?